# Satisfying a set of inequalities

Tags: inequality

Having a set of conditions (1)(2) and (3) as follows

> 1-$$\beta < 1$$
>   2-$$ \beta > \alpha$$
>   3-$$\alpha < 1$$

Can I say that the following inequality is incorrect?

$$1-\alpha -\beta <0$$

What is the conditions are

$$\alpha< 0.5$$
$$\beta<\alpha$$

Can I say that it is impossible to satisfy the following
$$2-3\alpha -2\beta <0$$

Thanks

Comment: No? Just choose e.g. $\alpha=1/2$, $\beta=3/4$...

Comment: Thanks I agree, can you please check my other set of conditions @saz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to solve such problems is to plot the conditions on a plane, as shown.  Then it becomes perfectly clear whether conditions are consistent, what values obey or disobey conditions, and so on.

I used *Mathematica*, with this function call:

```
    RegionPlot[{\[Beta] > \[Alpha], 
  1 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta] < 0, 
    \[Alpha] < 0.5, 
  2 - 3 \[Alpha] - 2 \[Beta] < 0}, 
 {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Italic, 18}, {Italic, 18}, None, None},
 FrameLabel -> {Text[Style["\[Alpha]", 28]], 
   Text[Style["\[Beta]", 28]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, can you tell me what software did you use to draw this?

Comment: @Tyrone  Do I get an up vote for my work?

Comment: can you please provide me a plot with the second question? I would very much appreciate it.